# What is origin of term "network" in Network Common Data Form (NetCDF) format specification

Tags: netcdf, terminology

I see [(on Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Data_Format) that the NetCDF format evolved from a specification for storing multidimensional data called the "Common Data Format".

Semantically... the word "network" has a very clear meaning to me in that a graph of some sort is implied, or that the format specifically is designed for use over a computer network, etc.

What is the origin of word "network" in the NetCDF format?

Comment: One might speculate that `graph` is intended from _This constitutes a dependency graph as shown in Figure 1, where the dark green boxes represent the initial targets for standardization and light green are the next targets_ ref [CF-netCDF Core and Extensions Primer](https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=43733)

Comment: Possibly worth asking the OGC NetCDF SWG mailing list ~ see https://www.ogc.org/projects/groups/netcdfswg

Comment: Looking at the CF-netCDF Core and Extensions Primer (linked above). I think the dependency graph mentioned refers to extension features that depend on other extension features. This seems quite complicated to me, since if I were to attempt to create a .nc file then I would have to take into account the extension features dependency graph (and I haven't heard of tools that do this automatically). Makes it seem like writing a CF compliant netCDF file is a huge undertaking.

Comment: On this page - https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/index.html. I see that one of the goals of netCDF is to allow for subsettting of large datasets so that access of datasets is efficient over networks. I wonder if this is it...

Comment: How does NetCDF differ from [CDF](https://cdf.gsfc.nasa.gov/)

Comment: I don't know - does it allow for requesting subsets of datasets over a network? (or would i need to download an entire CDF file before I could use it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's some [history of netCDF](https://docs.unidata.ucar.edu/netcdf/NUG/netcdf_data_set_components.html#background) in the NetCDF User's Guide. The term "network" was intended to indicate that the data files could be shared between different types of computers across computer networks. The Network File System ([NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System_(protocol))) was pretty new at the time and influenced the naming of netCDF. (I just checked with one of the original developers to confirm this.)

Comment: I would not have guessed that - thanks.